how to load the sale price based on the selecter with django
hi I am a beginner on django and I would like to display the sale price depending on the product selected, see my source codes below. I'm stuck and I can't unblock, please I need your help.
Thanks for your help
the sales model:
class Sale(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    sale_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    montant_total = models.CharField(max_length=15, default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.montant_total

the views :
def addSale(request=None):
    current_sale = Sale()
    list_user = User.objects.all().order_by('-username')
    list_product = Product.objects.all().order_by('-name')

    if request.POST:
        if request.POST.get('user') != "":
            current_sale.user = User.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('user'))
        if request.POST.get('product') != "":
            current_sale.product = Product.objects.get(id=request.POST.get('product'))
        if request.POST.get('quantity') != "":
            current_sale.quantity = request.POST.get('quantity')
        if request.POST.get('sale_price') != "":
            current_sale.sale_price = request.GET.get('price')
        if request.POST.get('montant_total') != "":
            current_sale.montant_total = request.POST.get('montant_total')
        current_sale.save()
        return redirect('products-list')
    
    context = {'sale': current_sale, 'list_user': list_user, 'list_product': list_product}
    return render(request, 'daara/add_sale.html', context)

the add_sale.html template:
<div class="card-body">
                       <form method="POST">
                            {% csrf_token %}

                                 <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="utilisateur">Utilisateur</label>
                                    <select
                                        class="form-control" name="user">
                                        <option value="1" selected="selected">Selectionez un utilisateur</option>
                                        {% for user in list_user %}
                                        {% if user.id == sale.user.id %}
                                        <option value="{{sale.user.id}}"  selected="selected">{{sale.user.username}}</option>
                                        {% else %}
                                        <option value="{{user.id}}">{{user.username}}</option>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                           
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="produit">Produit</label>
                                    <select
                                        class="form-control" name="product" id="product">
                                        <option value="0" selected="selected">Selectionez un produit</option>
                                        {% for product in list_product %}
                                        {% if product.id == sale.product.id %}
                                        <option value="{{sale.product.id}}"  selected="selected">{{sale.product.name}}</option>
                                        {% else %}
                                        <option value="{{product.id}}">{{product.name}}</option>
                                        {% endif %}
                                        {% endfor %}
                                    </select>
                                </div>
                           
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>

                                    <input type="number"
                                        class="form-control" id="qte" name="quantity" value="{{sale.quantity}}">
                                </div>
                           
                                <div class="form-group col-md-6">
                                    <label for="sale_price">Price</label><input type="number" step="0.01"
                                          class="form-control" id="product_price" name="sale_price" value="{{product.price}}">
                                </div>
                           
                                 <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="#montant">
                                    <label for="montant">Montant Total</label> <input  type="number" step="0.01"
                                        class="form-control" id="montant" name="montant_total" value="{{sale.montant_total}}">
                                </div>



                            <div class="text-end">
                                 <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'products-list' %}" type="button">Close</a>
                                <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit"  value="save">Save</button>

                           </div>
                       </form>
                       <p>{{product_id}}aaa</p>

                    </div>

the url:
path('ad-sale', views.addSale, name="ad-sale")

I'm stuck and I can't unblock, please I need your help

Note: request arguments are strings.
On your models, you have defined quantity and sale_price as IntegerFields.
class Sale(models.Model):
...
  quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
  sale_price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)

But on your view, you are not converting string arguments into integers while saving your Sale model instance.
Change your code to below:
def addSale(request=None):
    ...

    if request.POST:
       ...
        if request.POST.get('quantity') != "":
            current_sale.quantity = int(request.POST.get('quantity'))
        if request.POST.get('sale_price') != "":
            current_sale.sale_price = int(request.GET.get('price'))
        ...
        current_sale.save()
        return redirect('products-list')
     ...


Tip:
It is much better to use Django Forms to process user input rather than extracting each argument manually as you are doing.
link to Forms

Do you mean each Product has a pre-defined price, and you want this price shown when the corresponding product being selected?
If so, a quick solution would be display the price directly on the select option, which does NOT require any JavaScript.
Suppose your Product model defined as such. You need to modify its __str__ method for this answer to work.
class Product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=xxx)
    # According to your template, sale_price have 2 decimal 
    # places, conflict with your Sale model definition. 
    # Thus I change field type to DecimalField. 
    sale_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=12, decimal_places=2)
    # ... other fields
    def __str__(self):
        # django form calls this method when rendering ForeignKey options
        # EDITED: no need to show price
        return self.name

As @Hujaakbar suggested, the built-in ModelForm is the recommended way for data validation. And your view can be re-write as below
from django.forms import modelform_factory

def addSale(request):
    SaleForm = modelform_factory(Sale, fields='__all__')
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SaleForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('product-list')
    else:
        form = SaleForm()
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'daara/add_sale.html', context)

And your template
<div class="card-body">
    <form method="POST">
        {% csrf_token %}

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="utilisateur">Utilisateur</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="user">
                {% for option in form.user.subwidgets %}
                    {{ option }}
                {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
                           
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="produit">Produit</label>
            <select class="form-control" name="product" id="product">
                 {% for option in form.product.subwidgets %}
                     {{ option }}
                 {% endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
                           
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="quantity">Quantity</label>
            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="qte" name="quantity" value="{{form.quantity.value}}">
        </div>
                           
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
            <label for="sale_price">Price</label>
            <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="product_price" name="sale_price" value="{{form.sale_price.value}}">
        </div>
                           
        <div class="form-group col-md-6" id="#montant">
            <label for="montant">Montant Total</label>
            <input type="number" step="0.01" class="form-control" id="montant" name="montant_total" value="{{form.montant_total.value}}">
        </div>


        <div class="text-end">
            {# anchor tag does not support type="button" #}
            <a class="btn btn-secondary" href="{% url 'products-list' %}" type="button">Close</a>
            {# value="save" attribute has no effect here #}
            <button class="btn btn-success" type="submit" value="save">Save</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    {# The context has no product_id attribute #}
    <p>{{product_id}}aaa</p>
 
</div>

{# EDITED: some javascript to show sale price when product being selected #}
<script>
  const products = {
    {% for product in form.fields.product.queryset %}
    "{{ product.id }}": {{ prodcut.sale_price }},
    {% endfor %}
  };

  function syncSalePrice() {
    const elemProduct = document.querySelector("#product");
    const elemPrice = document.querySelector("#product_price");

    if (elemProduct.value) {
      elemPrice.value = products[elemProduct.value];
    } else {
      elemPrice.value = "";
    }
  }

  window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const elemProduct = document.querySelector("#product");
    elemProduct.addEventListener("change", syncSalePrice);
  });
</script>

Some extra opinion:

if Sale.sale_price always matched with Product.sale_price, then Sale.sale_price is not necessary and can be removed. You can get price like Sale.objects.annotate(price=F('product__sale_price'));
if montant_total is just sale_price * quantity, then it is also not necessary and can be removed. Similar as above, you can get total price like Sale.objects.annotate(total=F('product__sale_price')*F('quantity'));


thank you for your help but I would like that when you select a product that the sales price field automatically displays the price of the selected product

Some javascript would be required to achive such functionality. Check out my editted answer.
